Can I define multiple objectives for solver in excel without writing a macro?
I need to solve an equation for each cell of a column in excel by changing one variable (a separate cell in the sheet) that will impact all the cells. how can I do this in excel?

You really need to give us more detail. Perhaps a screenshot and some data that we can please with along with the formulas you're updating and the goal you need to achieve. Right now your question is very close to , "can I do formulas in Excel?"

Try:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040
Solver will search for a value to that fits your equation. This will work for a single cell.
Something similar to the below might work..
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/659443-solver-or-solver-table-help.html
Option Explicit

Public Sub Solver_Solution()
Dim myR
Dim c
Set myR = Range("C20", "C25")
For Each c In myR
    SolverOk SetCell:="$K$15", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=c.Value, ByChange:="$C$15"
    SolverSolve userfinish:=True
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cells(15, "C").Value
Next
End Sub

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/functions/solverok-function
The Solver add-in is not enabled by default. Before you can use this function, you must have the Solver add-in enabled and installed. For information about how to do that, see Using the Solver VBA Functions. After the Solver add-in is installed, you must establish a reference to the Solver add-in. In the Visual Basic Editor, with a module active, click References on the Tools menu, and then select Solver under Available References. If Solver does not appear under Available References, click Browse, and then open Solver.xlam in the \Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library\SOLVER subfolder.
(My solution is suggesting the use of macro to run the Solver function multiple times across different cells.)
